# Implementing TCP features over UDP: Linux functions to rewrite

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, udp

For a introductory networks course project, I am expected to implement features of TCP such as in-order delivery, reliability, flow control, congestion control using UDP as the transport protocol.

I am considering writing my library with functions similar to

1. socket
2. connect
3. send
4. recv

For example, as one might use

```
int tcp_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
```

to create a TCP IPv4 socket, a user can use

```
int tcp_sock = my_socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM_LITE, 0);
```

to create a socket of my implementation.

What other functions should I implement as a bare minimum?

Also, is there any file/files that represent the TCP implementation in Ubuntu?

Comment: You should check your assignment rubric for what your instructor expects. IMO mimicking the UNIX socket API verbatim would not be a very good design choice, especially since said API is based on syscalls, which are very limiting in terms of argument types. At the very least, use a struct pointer as a handle and not an int.

Comment: Really too broad for a SO question I think. But to answer just what you asked all you need is read and write operations.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo - The prof who generally teaches the course has left on short notice, and the current prof has no idea what he expects from a project. I am looking to give him a library that can be used to write an simple network program. I want to be able to write an application that demonstrates atleast flow control, such as file transfer. So, basically, I am basically creating my own assignment rubric here.

Comment: You shouldn't need to write your own implementation of TCP sockets, nor use built-in TCP sockets. From my experience in this kind of project, you most likely just need to create UDP sockets and just implement TCP features on top of that, which means you need to look at the packets sent and received and decide what to do with them in different situations

Comment: First of all, it is simply impossible to implement TCP over UDP in a application layer. TCP is NOT built on top of UDP, instead, it is branched off of IP. A lot of stuff happening in TCP should happen on the kernel level.

Comment: To give some color to what I've meant - TCP has a retransmission feature. Inside your library you will not be able to 'steal' the control from the main application to implement it.

Comment: @SergeyA they are not implementing TCP on top of UDP, but simply implementing some TCP features on top of UDP, ie. create some application features that make UDP have more reliable transmissions. That is definitely possible and is a good exercise for students to understand how TCP features work

Comment: @TSG If you are looking for something like a project spec for your problem, here's one from the computer networking class at UCLA: http://tinyurl.com/pf7qbd8

Comment: Nothing good comes from this excercise. If you want to learn how TCP works, implement a proper TCP on top of IP as network stack.

Comment: @SergeyA, I get that all TCP stuff happens at the transport layer, so I am creating sort of a in between application-transport layer. The aim of the project is to learn about TCP in general, as UDP is little more than link layer packet transport + checksum. Personally, I share your view that this sort of makeshift project does not help to learn about TCP, but it might give experience in developing applications using UDP but with some more requirements

Comment: @stakSmashr - Thanks. I wish I got a structured problem statement like that. 
Only difference is that I want to incorporate the error checking and handling into a lib so that the application looks as similar as a tcp application as possible. Not a problem, though

Comment: @SergeyA: Of course you can implement TCP over UDP. UDP is just IP with a port number stuck to it. Plus a checksum I think. Look at VPN clients which run TCP over UDP for an example. Or game clients which use UDP for STUN to get through NAT but then layer TCP on top.